# Link to start of current section, automatically, in ConTeXt?

Tags: cross-referencing, context, context-mkiv

I want page headers to link to the start of the current `\subject`, and – because I am automatically processing an XML document – I want to do this without manually entering the subject label. (This may also require automatically adding a label to the subject.) Is there a command/keyword that identifies the location of the last-defined subject head?

`\getmarking[subject]` fetches the subject title. Unfortunately, trying to set a label with `\reference[{\getmarking[subject]}]` gives an error.

Minimal example:

```
% Smaller pages make examples nicer: \input-ing a quote 
% will create multiple pages at once
\setuppapersize[A7][A7]
\setupinteraction[state=start]

%% I want people to be able to click this text to go to the start of the chapter
\setupheadertexts[{\sc \words \getmarking[subject]}][]
\setupheader[leftwidth=0.9\textwidth]
\setuppagenumbering[location={header,right}, style=os]

\setuphead[subject]
  [header=high,            % no header on the subject page
   page=right,
   % Keep track of the number (but don't print it)
   % This is so we can include \subjects in the ToC
   % (ToC not included in this example)
   incrementnumber=yes,
   number=no,
   interaction=list,       % link to the TOC
  ]

\starttext
  \subject{Water}
  \input bryson

  \subject{America}
  \input davis
\stoptext
```

Comment: OT: Using explicit formatting commands like `\sc \words` in ConText is a code smell. It is better to use `\setuoheader[style=...]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First the code:

```
\setuppapersize   [A7] [A7]
\setupinteraction [state=start, color=black, contrastcolor=black]

\setupheadertexts
  [{\placelist
    [subject]
    [alternative=f, criterium=section]}]
  []

\setupheader [leftwidth=0.9\textwidth]

\setuphead [subject]
  [page=right,
   incrementnumber=yes]

\starttext
  \subject{Water}
  \input bryson

  \subject{America}
  \input davis
\stoptext
```

The basic idea is to place a table of contents in the header with
only one entry, the current section. Depending on your requirements
this might be sufficient. If you need finer control over the list
placement use the following code:

```
\unprotect

\setupheadertexts
  [{\placelist
    [subject]
    [\c!alternative=toc:section, \c!criterium=\v!section]}]
  []

\definelistalternative
  [toc:section]
  [\c!renderingsetup=list:toc:section]

\startsetups [list:toc:section]
  \hbox\strc_lists_get_reference_attribute\v!all
    {\currentlistentrytitle}
\stopsetups

\protect
```

The `\hbox` in the `list:toc:section` setup is required to enable the
interaction. Using this method you have full control and the macro
`\currentlistentrytitle` which expands to the hyperlinked name of the current
section.

Comment: This works very nicely. The only problem is that manual delimitation does not work; and automatic delimitation only works without linkification, and v.v. But that problem is specific enough that I'll take it up on the mailing list, instead. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Solved it: the combination  `\setupheader[leftwidth=...]` + linkification by `\placelist` leads to no text limitation taking place. On the other hand, `\setupheader[leftwidth=...]` + no linkification + possible limitation by `\placelist` leads to `\setuphead`'s limitation winning (but no linkification). Removing `\setupheader[leftwidth=...]` solves the problem.